# Shorthand for getting nested values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutable.js

I've been looking for a nice way to get really nested values when one of the properties may be null or undefined.

Example object:

```
var a = {
    b: {
        c: {
            d: 10
        }
    }
}
```

Now let's say that this is the structure that the object has when it is fully populated but sometimes b is undefined or c or even d. In javascript I would possibly resort to something like this:

```
 var d = a && a.b && a.b.c && a.b.c.d // Now d has value d or some falsy value
```

In Immutable.js I can do the following (which I find way more clean):

```
var d = a.getIn(['b', 'c', 'd'], null)
```

This allows me to retrieve the value of d and even set the final parameter as the default value if anything fails on the way.

Can I do so something similar in js.

Comment: So make a method that does it.... reduce() is what I would use.

Comment: Nope, there isn't a built-in shorthand for that. That's why the people behind Immutable.js wrote that function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could reduce the array with the object, after checking value and type.

```js
function getIn(object, keys, def)  {
    return keys.reduce(function (o, k) {
        return o && typeof o === 'object' && k in o ? o[k] : def;
    }, object);
}

var a = { b: { c: { d: 10 } } };

console.log(getIn(a, ['b', 'c', 'd'], null));
console.log(getIn(a, ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], null));
```

Comment: it's like you made underscore.js .

Comment: i thought, it's more than that.

Comment: then give a try to make new js . `nina.js`